# SQL order top rows differently than the rest

Tags: mysql

Is there any way how to order top rows in a query in a different way than the rest? For example, if I have a list of products with name and price, I would like to get the list ordered in a way that 10 most expensive products are on top ordered by price desc, and the rest below is ordered by product name.

What comes in my mind is something like this:

```
SELECT id,name, price FROM products ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
SELECT id,name,price FROM products
  WHERE id NOT IN
  (SELECT id FROM products ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 10)
  ORDER BY name
```

but this query does not execute, it prints `Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY`, furthermore if I wrap the selects into another selects, it prints `LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery`. Any idea?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
SELECT 1 a, id,name, price FROM products ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, id,name,price FROM products
  WHERE id NOT IN
  (SELECT id FROM products ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 10)
)
order by a*price desc, name
```

Comment: well.. not sure about the LIMIT in the subquery.  Maybe the idea of the 1 and 0 can let you multiple the price on the correct subset if you can find a way to do the limit (by maybe creating views?)